# OnActivityResult is never called

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I have two standalone applications. Application A and Application B. I want to start activity in application B from Application A and get the results back. In application B there is one more activity. From B second acitivty i get result to B's first activity. Now I want these result back to Application A. But OnActivityResult in A is never called. Following is the code.

Application A:

```
public void onClickBtnToApplicationB(View v) {
        try {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
            final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("pakacagename","package.class");
            intent.setComponent(cn);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                 
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        //handle Exception
        } 
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE:
               handleResult(resultCode, intent);
               break;
        }
    }

    public void handleResult(int resultCode, Intent intentResult) {
        switch (resultCode) {
            case RESULT_OK:
                String Result = intentResult.getStringExtra("RESULT");
                // I need Results from Application B here..
                break;

             case RESULT_CANCELED:
                break;
        }
      }
```

Application B Activity 1.class:

```
Intent s = new Intent(1.this,2.class);
startActivityForResult(s, REQUEST_CODE_B);
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intentResult) {     
    switch(requestCode){
        case REQUEST_CODE_B:
            handleResult(resultCode, intentResult);
    }
}

public void handleResult(int resultCode, Intent intentResult) {
    switch (resultCode) {
    case RESULT_OK:
        String scanResult = intentResult.getStringExtra("RESULT");
        Intent newintent = new Intent();
        newintent.putExtra("RESULT", scanResult);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, newintent);
        finish();
        break;

    case RESULT_CANCELED:
        break;
}
```

Comment: Is application B also your application?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29):

> Note that this method should only be used with Intent protocols that
>   are defined to return a result. In other protocols (such as
>   ACTION_MAIN or ACTION_VIEW), you may not get the result when you
>   expect. For example, if the activity you are launching uses the
>   singleTask launch mode, it will not run in your task and thus you will
>   immediately receive a cancel result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am novice in android. What could be the possible solution in such scenario. How can I integrate two applications. or in other words, How can I call the standalone application and get results from that application. your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Based on the documentation, it would appear that avoiding singleTask launch mode and renaming the intent action would eliminate the issue. If you look at OpenIntents (source available), you can see how they solved it.

Comment: I now use the action name for calling application B but I dont know how to get the results. I couldn't understand Openintents.  Application A onActivityResult is still not being called.